# how back reference works in unix

Tags: unix

I have a file "file7.txt"
The contents of file7.txt,
[image]

I want to know how the back reference works with grep command.
when i type the commands, i get the following results,
[image]

So now i want to know how this works.

Comment: What did you try with back reference with this data.share the the things that you tried. So that it would be easy for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would explain you the first grep that you have tried.

```
grep '\([a-z]\)\1'
```

This matches the sample string with 'first character' same as the next character.

> f i **l l** i n g

- Grep matches the first character within 'a' to 'z'.
- At the beginnign it checks for every character, one by one.
- $1 holds the character, The pattern is to have the next character as 1.
- You need a way of remembering what you found, and seeing if the same pattern occurred again.
- You can mark part of a pattern using "(" and ")".
- You can recall the remembered pattern with "\" followed by a single digit.
- You can have 9 different remembered patterns.
- This reduces the pattern search efficiently and saves your time.

This is how all the back references work.

Comment: OK explain me the 2nd one

Comment: The second one too works the same as first. You have grouped two patterns, such that $1 which holds the first grouping , and $2 holds the second grouping. As your patterns says  '\([a-z]\)\([a-z]\)\2\1'' which matches by grouped

Comment: Hope you would have understood the third too.